# Trying to write and erase the text every time on my screen in uwp

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I'm trying to write and erase the text every time on my screen in uwp but it works only for the first time after that neither i can write on screen and neither i can erase what i have written .Also color picker is not disappearing after the  selection of color

Xaml code

```
<Page xmlns:my="using:Coding4Fun.Toolkit.Controls" 
    x:Class="ABCD_kids.WorkBook"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:ABCD_kids"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"     
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid>
        <Grid.Background>
            <ImageBrush Stretch="Fill" ImageSource="ms-appx:///ABCD/Workbook_bg.png"/>
        </Grid.Background>
        <!--<InkCanvas Name="ink"/>-->
        <RelativePanel x:Name="HomePanel" Grid.Row="0" Canvas.ZIndex="1">
            <Image x:Name="Home" Source="ABCD/Home.png"
               RelativePanel.AlignLeftWithPanel="True"
                   Margin="10,10,0,0" Tapped="HomePage"
               Width="40" Height="40"/>
            <Rectangle x:Name="Bg_Rect" Fill="White"
                       Width="310" Height="80"
                       RelativePanel.AlignHorizontalCenterWithPanel="True"
                       Margin="0,52,0,0"/>
            <Image x:Name="Alph_cap" Source="ABCD/Cap_alpha/Cap_0.png"
               RelativePanel.AlignLeftWithPanel="True" 
                   RelativePanel.Below="Home"
                   Margin="60,-9,0,0"
               Width="100" Height="100"/>
            <TextBlock x:Name="CapAlphaName"                
                Text="Ant"
                FontFamily="Font/VAG Round.TTF#VAG Round"
               RelativePanel.AlignTopWithPanel="True"
               RelativePanel.RightOf="Alph_cap"
               Foreground="BlueViolet"
               Margin="10,70,0,0" FontSize="39" FontStretch="UltraCondensed">
            </TextBlock>
            <Grid x:Name="Bg_BigRect" Background="White"
                       Width="310" Height="440"
                       RelativePanel.Below="Bg_Rect"
                       Margin="24,10,0,0">
                <Image x:Name="Trans_Tex" Source="WorkBook/T0.png"                              
               Margin="-10,0,0,20" 
               Width="310" Height="370"/>
                <InkCanvas x:Name="ink"/>
            </Grid>
            <Image x:Name="WPrev" Source="ABCD/Previous.png"
               RelativePanel.AlignBottomWithPanel="True"                   
                Margin="49,0,0,10" Tapped="WPrevTap"
               Width="40" Height="40"/>
            <my:ColorPicker x:Name="W_Paints"
                            Margin="216,203,-6,0" Height="374"
                            Width="374" VerticalAlignment="Top"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                            Visibility="Collapsed"
                            ColorChanged="CPtest_ColorChanged"/>           
            <!--<controls:ColorPicker x:Name="W_Paints"
                            Margin="216,203,-6,0" Height="40"
                            Width="40" VerticalAlignment="Top"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Left"></controls:ColorPicker>-->

            <Image x:Name="W_Paint" Source="ABCD/W_Paint.png"
               RelativePanel.AlignBottomWithPanel="True"
                   RelativePanel.RightOf="WPrev"
                   Margin="17,0,0,10" Tapped="W_Paintt"
               Width="40" Height="40">

            </Image>
            <Image x:Name="W_Clear" Source="ABCD/Clear_all.png"
               RelativePanel.AlignBottomWithPanel="True"
                   RelativePanel.RightOf="W_Paint" Tapped="W_ClearTap"
                   Margin="17,0,0,10"
               Width="40" Height="40"/>
            <Image x:Name="W_Mactive" Source="ABCD/Music_active.png"
               RelativePanel.AlignBottomWithPanel="True"
                   RelativePanel.RightOf="W_Clear"
                   Margin="17,0,0,10" Tapped="W_MactiveTap"
               Width="40" Height="40"/>
            <Image x:Name="W_Fwd" Source="ABCD/Forward.png"
               RelativePanel.AlignBottomWithPanel="True"
                   RelativePanel.RightOf="W_Mactive"
                   Margin="17,0,0,10" Tapped="W_FwdTap"
               Width="40" Height="40"/>

        </RelativePanel>
        <MediaElement x:Name="mediaWorkbook" Source="/Video/workbook.mp3" Volume="0.4"  />
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

c# code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.Foundation.Collections;
using Windows.UI.Core;
using Windows.UI.Input.Inking;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;


// The Blank Page item template is documented at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=234238

namespace ABCD_kids
{
    /// <summary>
    /// An empty page that can be used on its own or navigated to within a Frame.
    /// </summary>
    public sealed partial class WorkBook : Page
    {

        public WorkBook()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            ink.InkPresenter.InputDeviceTypes = CoreInputDeviceTypes.Mouse | CoreInputDeviceTypes.Touch;     

            // Set initial ink stroke attributes.
            InkDrawingAttributes drawingAttributes = new InkDrawingAttributes();
            drawingAttributes.Color = Windows.UI.Colors.Black;
            drawingAttributes.IgnorePressure = false;
            drawingAttributes.FitToCurve = true;
            ink.InkPresenter.UpdateDefaultDrawingAttributes(drawingAttributes);

        }


        string[] CapsAlpha = new string[] { "Ant", "ant", "Bear", "bear", "Cat", "cat", "Dog", "dog", "Elephant", "elephant", "Frog", "frog", "Giraffe", "giraffe", "Hippo", "hippo", "Ice-Cream", "ice-cream", "Jellyfish", "jellyfish", "Kite", "kite", "Lion", "lion", "Mouse", "mouse", "Nest", "nest", "Owl", "owl",
            "Parrot", "parrot", "Queen", "queen", "Rabbit", "rabbit", "Sheep", "sheep", "Toy", "toy", "Umbrella", "umbrella", "Vulture", "vulture", "Watch", "watch", "X-ray", "x-ray", "Yak", "yak", "Zebra", "zebra" };                     
        int currentIndex = 0;
        private void WPrevTap(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            currentIndex--;
            if (currentIndex < 0)
            {
                currentIndex = 0;
                return;
            }

            Trans_Tex.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///WorkBook/T" + currentIndex + ".png"));
            Alph_cap.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///ABCD/MixCapSmall/CS" + currentIndex + ".png"));
            CapAlphaName.Text = CapsAlpha[currentIndex];
            //var speechText = this.CapAlphaName.Text;            
        }

        private void W_FwdTap(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            currentIndex++;
            if (currentIndex > 51)
            {
                currentIndex = 25;
                return;
            }
            Trans_Tex.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///WorkBook/T" + currentIndex + ".png"));
            Alph_cap.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///ABCD/MixCapSmall/CS" + currentIndex + ".png"));            
            CapAlphaName.Text = CapsAlpha[currentIndex];           

            }

        private void W_MactiveTap(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if ((W_Mactive.Source as BitmapImage).UriSource == new Uri("ms-appx:///ABCD/Music_active.png", UriKind.Absolute))
            {
                W_Mactive.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///ABCD/Music_mute.png"));
                mediaWorkbook.Stop();
            }
            else
            {
                W_Mactive.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///ABCD/Music_active.png"));
                mediaWorkbook.Play();
            }
        }


         private void W_Paintt(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            W_Paints.Visibility = Visibility;
        }
        private void CPtest_ColorChanged(object sender, Windows.UI.Color color)
        {
            ink.InkPresenter.InputDeviceTypes = CoreInputDeviceTypes.Mouse | CoreInputDeviceTypes.Touch;

            // Set initial ink stroke attributes.
            InkDrawingAttributes drawingAttributes = new InkDrawingAttributes();
            drawingAttributes.Color = color;
            drawingAttributes.IgnorePressure = false;
            drawingAttributes.FitToCurve = true;
            ink.InkPresenter.UpdateDefaultDrawingAttributes(drawingAttributes);

            //Bg_BigRect.Background = new SolidColorBrush(color);
        }

        private void W_ClearTap(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.ink.InkPresenter.InputProcessingConfiguration.Mode = InkInputProcessingMode.Erasing;
            //ink.InkPresenter.Strokes.Clear();
            //Windows.UI.Input.Inking.InkInputProcessingMode.Erasing;
            //this.ink.Strokes.Remove();
        }



        private void HomePage(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage));
        }


    }
}
```

Refer image[image]

Comment: what do you mean by "write and erase the text every time on my screen"? It's not clear which parts of the code you've pasted relate to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> it works only for the first time after that neither i can write on screen and neither i can erase what i have written .

It's because you have not reset the `ink.InkPresenter.InputProcessingConfiguration.Mode = InkInputProcessingMode.Inking` after you click erase button.

> Also color picker is not disappearing after the selection of color

The same thing, after you select color, you would need to set its Visibility property value manually.

I'v helped you edit your code, please refer to the following code for reference:

```cs
private void CPtest_ColorChanged(object sender, Windows.UI.Color color)
{
    ink.InkPresenter.InputDeviceTypes = CoreInputDeviceTypes.Mouse | CoreInputDeviceTypes.Touch;

    // Set initial ink stroke attributes.
    InkDrawingAttributes drawingAttributes = new InkDrawingAttributes();
    drawingAttributes.Color = color;
    drawingAttributes.IgnorePressure = false;
    drawingAttributes.FitToCurve = true;
    ink.InkPresenter.UpdateDefaultDrawingAttributes(drawingAttributes);

    W_Paints.Visibility = W_Paints.Visibility == Visibility.Collapsed ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
    this.ink.InkPresenter.InputProcessingConfiguration.Mode = InkInputProcessingMode.Inking;
}
```